# cordova building an Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10+) on command line - Visual Studio PATH variable

Tags: cordova, build, windows-phone, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build a windows phone 10 build with cordova.

System information:

```
cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7 
OS: Windows 10 
Node Version: v6.11.0
```

When I run this command: **cordova requirements**

> Requirements check results for **android**:
> Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
> Android SDK: installed true
> Android target: installed
> android-25,android-24,Google Inc.:Google
> APIs:24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17
> Gradle: installed E:\Android\Android
> Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
>
> Requirements check results for **ios**:
> Apple OS X: not installed Cordova tooling for iOS requires Apple OS X
>
> **Requirements check results for windows**:
> Windows OS: installed Windows
> 10 MSBuild Tools: installed 14.0
> Visual Studio: **not installed** Required
> version of Visual Studio not found. Please install Visual Studio 2015
> Community from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs
> Windows SDK: installed 10.0
> Windows Phone SDK: installed 10.0
> Error: Some of requirements check failed

I have **Visual Studio 2017** installed on my machine.
I have added these variables to my system PATH:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\

I am not sure why it is saying that I do not have VS installed.
Is there a specific .exe file that cordova is looking for?

Comment: Have you install [VS tools for cordova](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/) ?

Comment: Yes, I have the cordova 6.3.1 tool set installed.

Comment: Do you tried to launch your project (created directly in VS), without pass by CLI ?

Comment: It works when I build from Visual Studio but not from the command line.

Comment: Ok, [read this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html#project-configuration) and try to build your project with `--appx`